# Fetch is giving "Network Request Failed" in android release app even for HTTPS requests. Why?

Tags: android, react-native

Even If I'm giving an HTTPS request(which is said to be acceptable in android OS version 9), still it gives a "`Network Request Failed"` Error.

I have tried the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` workaround for http requests but it didn't work. Then used firebase functions for https APIs still it gives the same error.

Comment: check internet permissions ;)

Comment: I've added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml. Is there anything that I have to add for the permissions. This only happens in the release. Works fine when in debug.